# Displaying TraMineR (R) dendrograms in text/table format

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dendrogram, traminer

I use the following R code to generate a dendrogram (see attached picture) with labels based on TraMineR sequences:

```
library(TraMineR)
library(cluster)
clusterward <- agnes(twitter.om, diss = TRUE, method = "ward")
plot(clusterward, which.plots = 2, labels=colnames(twitter_sequences))
```

The full code (including dataset) can be found [here](https://github.com/aronlindberg/VOSS-Sequencing-Toolkit/blob/master/twitter_exploratory_analysis/analyzing_several_twitter_repos.R).

As informative as the dendrogram is graphically, it would be handy to get the same information in text and/or table format. If I call any of the aspects of the object clusterward (created by agnes), such as "order" or "merge" I get everything labeled using numbers rather than the names I get from `colnames(twitter_sequences)`. Also, I don't see how I can output the groupings represented graphically in the dendrogram.

To summarize: **How can I get the cluster output in text/table format with the labels properly displayed using R and ideally the traminer/cluster libraries?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question concerns the `cluster` package. The help page for the `agnes.object` returned by `agnes` 
(See http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/cluster/html/agnes.object.html ) states that this object contains an `order.lab` component "similar to `order`, but containing observation labels instead of observation numbers. This component is only available if the original observations were labelled."

The dissimilarity matrix (`twitter.om` in your case) produced by TraMineR does currently not retain the sequence labels as row and column names. To get the `order.lab` component you have to manually assign sequence labels as both the `rownames` and `colnames` of your `twitter.om` matrix. I illustrate here with the `mvad` data provided by the TraMineR package.

```
library(TraMineR)
data(mvad)
## attaching row labels 
rownames(mvad) <- paste("seq",rownames(mvad),sep="")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[17:86]) 
## computing the dissimilarity matrix
dist.om <- seqdist(mvad.seq, method = "OM", indel = 1, sm = "TRATE")
## assigning row and column labels 
rownames(dist.om) <- rownames(mvad) 
colnames(dist.om) <- rownames(mvad) 
dist.om[1:6,1:6]

## Hierarchical cluster with agnes library(cluster) 
cward <- agnes(dist.om, diss = TRUE, method = "ward")

## here we can see that cward has an order.lab component 
attributes(cward)
```

That is for getting `order` with sequence labels rather than numbers. But now it is not clear to me which cluster outcome you want in text/table form. From the dendrogram you decide of where you want to cut it, i.e., the number of groups you want and cut the dendrogram with `cutree`, e.g. `cl.4 <- cutree(clusterward1, k = 4)`. The result `cl.4` is a vector with the cluster membership for each sequence and you get the list of the members of group 1, for example, with `rownames(mvad.seq)[cl.4==1]`.

Alternatively, you can use the `identify` method (see `?identify.hclust`) to select the groups interactively from the plot, but need to pass the argument as  `as.hclust(cward)`. Here is the code for the example

```
## plot the dendrogram
plot(cward, which.plot = 2, labels=FALSE)

## and select the groups manually from the plot
x <- identify(as.hclust(cward)) ## Terminate with second mouse button

## number of groups selected
length(x)
## list of members of the first group
x[[1]]
```

Hope this helps.